# 'To lower/raise the blinds' or 'to draw the blinds?'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, verbs

I'm an English learner and I'd like to know which verb should I use when using the word venetian blinds. Do you say 'to **raise/lower** the blinds' or 'to **pull** the blinds **up/down**?' or 'to **draw** the blinds'? + What would you say if you just wanted to turn the slats - would you say something like '**Close/open** the blinds, please.'?

Answer (score 1):

It would be understood in all variations that you proposed. However, "draw the blinds" only applies to closing/lowering, generally, not opening/raising.

If the blinds are vertical (from the top of the window) using raise/lower or pull up/down would both be correct.

If they are down and you want to adjust the slats I would use close/open. You may need to specify in that case, though, by saying "close/open the slats" rather than "close/open the blinds." This is something that even native English speakers have been known to get confused about at times!

Comment: I think in this case, open and close is the clearest example. There are many other idiomatic version that don't follow common rules. For example, in the southern US, it's not uncommon to hear "Let the blinds up" to mean "Raise/Open the blinds"

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have mentioned that I'm an American English speaker from the Midwest. There are local colloquialisms and idiomatic phrases in other parts of the world, I'm sure!

Comment: I would note that "draw back the blinds" would be the opposite of "draw the blinds" :)